# Memory reallocation in vectors

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and want to avoid newbie performance pitfalls.

Can **erasing** elements from a vector possibly cause a memory reallocation?

I'm working on a function that will add elements to a vector, and possibly erase some elements in the same frame.

Comment: *and want to avoid newbie performance pitfalls.* -- Erasing items will not cause a reallocation.  However it *does* require moving items to fill in the hole created by the removed element.  That in itself may be an issue of performance.

Comment: If you don't care the order of elements, you may swap the item to remove and the last item, and use pop_back.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, this is the kind of issue i was overlooking. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, it **does not**. If it did, it would invalidate all iterators, but, as [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) states, it only *Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.*